# Modifying Twilio call in progress causes disconnect

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have a node backend twilio version 3.50 and web js client using twilio.js 1.12 and I am tryin to play a message to the call in progress before starting recording process. This is my server side code:

```
            client.calls(callSid)
                .update({twiml: '<Response><Say>Ahoy there</Say></Response>'})
                .then(call => {
                    client.calls(callSid)
                        .recordings
                        .create({
                            recordingChannels: 'dual',
                            recordingStatusCallback: callbackUrl,
                        })
                        .then(recording => {                        
                            res.json(recording);
                        })
                        .catch(e => {
                            console.error(e);
                        });
                });
```

When server executes this code I can hear the message but after that call ends immediately. As I already figured out the message is actually played in a separate call with new id but why does client disconnects when child call ends?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a [conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/contact-center-blueprint/call-control-concepts), to pin up the call legs. If not, when you modify one call leg, the other call leg will drop.

You can use the [conference participant resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource), to create a conference participant with `earlyMedia` set to true, and you should be able to inject an [announcement](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/07/twilio-conference-now-supports-announcements.html) into the conference. Otherwise, once the conference is being mixed, you can use announcements for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed reply! Checking it now.